# Flooded world novel. Scottish dialogue. Frozen pods holding disease victims

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this U.K. paperback about a decade ago, but I don't think it was a new release

Most of the Earth is flooded and the story takes place aboard loads of giant ships moored by the remains of the Scottish highlands.

The protagonist is an ex-marine, but his military service was like 50 mile swims and then knife fights in midnight lagoons

The dialogue is written in "hoots mon, it's a braw bricht nicht the noo" Scottish talking

The hero needs to find out who infected his girl with this stone disease, her and thousands of others are stored in sealed pods, each can only be released for burial once their DNA has been coded so they don't become a 'Typhoid Mary' for this disease. To do this the individual infection sources need to be included in the coding.

There are lines referring to the Great Floods and mass city drownings.

On-shore there are constant battles between survivalists and wild tribes; sometimes American tourists from the Rockies travel there with hunting rifles and get involved with the battles.

I think the body pods were named 'Kists'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it! I did a lot of searching for Scottish sci fi novels.

> **[But n Ben A-Go-Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/But%27n%27Ben_A-Go-Go)** is a science fiction work by Scots writer Matthew Fitt, notable for being entirely in the Scots language. The novel was first published in 2000.
>
> Set in the year 2090, the book depicts a future world where global warming has caused sea level to rise considerably. The Highlands of Scotland are the only unsubmerged part of Britain – the Highlands now being known as the Drylands. Damage to the ozone layer has resulted in much higher levels of UV light and so sunburn and skin cancer are serious issues – most people do not venture outside unless entirely necessary, and carry high factor suncream and anti-cancer kits.
>
> **Most of the world's population were wiped out in "God's flood"; the survivors live in collections of floating oil-platform-like city structures, known as parishes.** The story takes place around the seas and drylands that were once Scotland – initially Port, a collection of parishes (named after towns around Scotland) attached to what was once Greenock by underwater cables.
>
> The Population of Port are watched constantly by a totalitarian government; there are class divides in the parishes (there is an underclass of Danish refugees living in many of the lower levels); the climate of Earth is now inhospitable. **In addition to these problems, Senga, a new strain of HIV infects much of the population. There is no cure, and the entire population is infected with the Mowdy virus (similar to HIV) and are dependent on government issued medication to suppress Senga.** Senga also becomes active if individuals engage in sex – reproduction is performed using laboratory techniques, and only virtual sex is possible.
>
> Anyone who develops Senga is put into isolation for the virus to run its course – **these people are kistit – entombed in capsules in huge hospitals.** Victim's thoughts are visualised by 'thochtscreens' on each kist.